# Jquery file upload, how to return response with symfony2?

Tags: symfony, jquery-file-upload

I want to upload a file with jquery-file-upload (blueimp) in cross domain to a symfony2 application.

To do this, client side :

```
SLjQuery(function () {
    'use strict';

    SLjQuery('#media_answer_answer').fileupload({
        url: "http://recrutonline.dev/app_dev.php/api/media/questionnaire-test-media/uploads",
        dataType: 'text',
        formData: SLjQuery('form#answer_process_form').serializeArray(),
        forceIframeTransport: true,
        redirect: 'http://mywebsite.dev/result.html?%s',
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log('upload ok ', data)
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            console.log(data.loaded/data.total);
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            SLjQuery('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !SLjQuery.support.fileInput)
      .parent().addClass(SLjQuery.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled')
    ;
});
```

in my controller symfony :

```
public function postMediaUploadAction(Request $request)
{
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $redirectResponse = $requestData['redirect']; // http://mywebsite.dev/result.html?%s
    //...
    //here process on data & get file uploaded
    //...

    //example of data I would send back to the client : http://mywebsite.dev/result.html?{'file':[{'name':'filetoupload.jpg'}]}
    $response = str_replace("%s", "{'file':[{'name':'filetoupload.jpg'}]}", $redirectresponse); // is it the good method ?
    return ??
}
```

Now client side response received :

in console.log of 'done' parameter of ajax function:

```
data.result -> undefined
data.textStatus -> "success"
```

I tried to return many things but result is still undefined. So do you know what kind of data I have to return ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the OneupUploaderBundle?

If so, don't post the file to your own controller but send it to the [Oneup uploader endpoint](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-prepare-your-frontend). You can then return custom data by [implementing an event listener](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/response.md).

For instance:

```
namespace Foo\BarBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;

class UploadListener
{
    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        if ($file = $event->getFile()) {
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            $response['file']['name'] = $file->getKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Register this event listener in your services.yml (or xml file):

```
# Event listener to handle uploaded files
foo_bundle.upload_listener:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.default_uploader, method: onUpload }
```

When you *do* want to handle the upload yourself, which I don't recommend, return a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` or even better a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse` object. See [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response).

Comment: I'm not using OneupUploaderBundle, but I'm going to try